# change a UILabel position on different storyboard targets

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel, target

I have an iOS app that has one project and multiple targets (for different deployments). I want to duplicate one of my UIViewControllers in the story board and move the location of a UILabel in it for only one of my targets.
I tried to copy-paste the controller, but then when removing a target from the copied controller, removes it from the pasted controller.
does anyone have a solution?